# In "Interview with a vampire" why did they only execute Claudia, when Louis killed a vampire as well?

Tags: vampire-chronicles, interview-with-the-vampire

Obviously, it's a crime to kill your own kind. Louis did kill a vampire (one of those who appeared to be nothing more than mindless corpses) when they traveled throughout eastern Europe. So why wasn't he punished by death too?

Comment: Hmmm, it's been a while.  I can't recall him killing a vampire before Claudia's execution.  Probably I'm in the minority, but it might help if you gave more detail?  (Also, it's not like Claudia *actually* killed a vampire, as you find out by the end of the movie.)

Comment: It happened when Louis and Claudia traveled throughout Eastern Europe in search of other vampires. Claudia and Louis arrive at a village and the woman in the inn tells them that the vampire comes from some ruins to the north, so they set off in their carriage to check it out.
Claudia and Louis arrive at the ruins and find the vampire but it's nothing more than a mindless animated corpse. It attacks them and Louis fights the vampire and kills him.

Comment: Been a while for me to. Did anyone know about it?

Comment: I seem to recall there might have been some bias in Claudia's case as it was "forbidden to create one so young" (or something to that effect).

Comment: Louis **was** sentenced to death. According to the Wikipedia entry he was "...locked in a coffin to starve" (or bricked up in the film - there's no suggestion that it was temporary, other than Armand wanted Louis and probably designed his punishment so he could be rescued). My recollection is that vampires can go into hibernation (Lestat hibernates for a while in one of the other books), so it might be that Louis' punishment was worse than death. He made a "child vampire", so a quick death is too good for him. Claudia, being the child vampire, was merely disposed of quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The killing of Vampires is not against "the rules", so to speak.  The killing of your *maker* is. This was done by Claudia with Louis' help after the fact (he was consigned to be locked in a crypt and continual starvation).
Claudia was also singled out because she was an abomination to the Vampires. No one of her age at "death" (a child) were supposed to be turned.

Comment: I think you're right. (Though it's been a few decades since I read the book.) There was no absolute prohibition against one vampire fighting and/or killing another under any and all circumstances . . . but apparently those vampires in Paris felt you had to draw the line *somewhere.*